# Android link to activity in edittext and textview

Tags: android, android-activity, textview, android-edittext, hyperlink

I want a text in an edittext or textview with some clickable words(like links) in it. I want that when the user clicks a link, another activity will be started. How to do this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to [linkify](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2008/03/linkify-your-text.html) your text.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use webview for your purpose

```
web.loadData(data, mimetype, encoding); 
web.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() { 

@Override public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {

      if (url.contains("some substring from your url ")) {
        // start new activity
        return true;
      }
      else {
        return false;
      }

    }
});
```

Comment: But I don't want to show a web page, but an acitity i've made when i click on a word